# Angular displacement of a certain pendulum bob

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The angular displacement $\theta$ of a certain pendulum bob in terms of its initial displacement $\theta_0$ is
$$\theta=\theta_0 \cos wt\ .$$
If $w=3.00$ (rad/s) and $\theta_0=\pi/30$ rad, draw two cycles for the resulting equation.

I honestly have no idea how to start this.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please feel free to share what you have tried so far. If you aren't sure where to start then sharing some of your difficulties could help us provide you with a good answer.

Comment: The amplitude of the function is $ \ \theta_0 \ $ .  Remember that the period of a sine or cosine function is $ \ T = \frac{2 \pi}{\omega} \ . $

Answer (score 0):

You can start by plugging in values for $t$, calculating values for $\theta$, and plotting them.  You need to figure out how long in $t$ is two cycles-for one cycle the argument of $\cos$ has to increase by $2\pi$. A spreadsheet and copy down makes the calculation easy, and it will graph for you, too.